# Casting the Bigint number Returns NULL

Tags: sql, hive, casting, numeric, bigint

I need o convert a integer  value to the highest data type in hive as my value is of 25 digits

```
select cast(18446744073709551614 as bigint);
```

`NULL` value will be returned for the above select stmnt;

I am very well aware that the supplied number is greater than the largest number of `Bigint`. But we are getting such values upon which i have to calculate the max,min,sum,avg

So how can i cast this type of values so that i will not get the NULLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `decimal(38, 0)` for storing numbers bigger than BIGINT, it can store 38 digits. [BIGINT](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-NumericTypes) can store 19 digits. Read also manual about [decimal type](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-decimal).

For literals postfix `BD` is required. Example:

```
hive> select CAST(18446744073709551614BD AS DECIMAL(38,0))+CAST(18446744073709551614BD AS DECIMAL(38,0));
OK
36893488147419103228
Time taken: 0.334 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select CAST(18446744073709551614BD AS DECIMAL(38,0))*2;
OK
36893488147419103228
Time taken: 0.129 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked out, after converting the input to string itself and then to decimal